# I have Minify problem

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css

I have just tried analysing my webshop: [www.tekompagniet.dk](http://tekompagniet.dk) using a chrome-extention, and it seems like a css and js minification would do a great job. However, I have troubles doing this without getting a lot of bugs.

I have tried fooman speedster before, but get some weird as looking pictures... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Zyberchief and welcome to MageOverflow. Minifier working afaik great - as long as your code is really valid JS code (especially if you have closing ; at the end of each line)

So I think the solution for you is to fix all the bugs, which avoids to use minifying. I don't know any minifier which is able to minify without having set all the `;` at the right place.

Comment: I concur. Write proper code, Javascript line endings are **semicolons (;)** not newline. Lazycoding does not belong in web design and bites mightily when you start realizing that all those newline characters, tabs and spaces really add up. This is especially important if you minify HTML and have inlined scripting. Every page `<script />` that's missing a line ending `;` breaks horribly and it's horribly time consuming to track it all down.